# Loop through each element with class and append its text JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loops, foreach

I have a need to loop through several `<div>` elements with the class `.spr-review-content` and grab the text of each `<span class="image_src">`. Then use that text as the `src` of an appended `<img>` for that `div`.  I almost have it working but the code grabs all the text of each span and uses that as the image source for each image instead of just that one span's text.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Display Image Test</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="spr-review" id="spr-review-49046513">
        <div class="spr-review-header">
        <span class="spr-starratings spr-review-header-starratings">
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
        </span>
        <h3 class="spr-review-header-title">Teething Toy</h3>
        <span class="spr-review-header-byline"><strong>Jessi</strong> on <strong>Oct 06, 2017</strong></span>
    </div>

    <div class="spr-review-content">
        <p class="spr-review-content-body">Beautifully made item, and the sweetest photo prop. Was a 'must have' piece for my babe. Thanks!</p>
    </div>
    <span class="image_src">https://img0.etsystatic.com/130/0/8943009/iap_300x300.1065344898_2arw8sir.jpg</span>
    <div class="spr-review-footer">
        <a href="#" class="spr-review-reportreview" onclick="SPR.reportReview(49046513);return false" id="report_49046513" data-msg="This review has been reported">Report as Inappropriate</a>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="spr-review" id="spr-review-49046513">
        <div class="spr-review-header">
        <span class="spr-starratings spr-review-header-starratings">
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
        </span>
        <h3 class="spr-review-header-title">Teething Toy</h3>
        <span class="spr-review-header-byline"><strong>Jessi</strong> on <strong>Oct 06, 2017</strong></span>
    </div>

    <div class="spr-review-content">
        <p class="spr-review-content-body">Beautifully made item, and the sweetest photo prop. Was a 'must have' piece for my babe. Thanks!</p>
    </div>
    <span class="image_src">https://img0.etsystatic.com/130/0/8943009/iap_300x300.1065344898_2arw8sir.jpg</span>
    <div class="spr-review-footer">
        <a href="#" class="spr-review-reportreview" onclick="SPR.reportReview(49046513);return false" id="report_49046513" data-msg="This review has been reported">Report as Inappropriate</a>
  </div>
  </div>


  <script>

        $('.spr-review-content').each(function(){

        var img_src = $('.image_src').text();

        $('<img />', {'class' : 'review_img', 'src' : img_src , appendTo : this});

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change to this

```
var img_src = $(this).next('.image_src').text();
```

```js
$('.spr-review-content').each(function() {

  var img_src = $(this).next('.image_src').text();
  $('<img />', {
    'class': 'review_img',
    'src': img_src,
    appendTo: this
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spr-review" id="spr-review-49046513">
  <div class="spr-review-header">
    <span class="spr-starratings spr-review-header-starratings">
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
        </span>
    <h3 class="spr-review-header-title">Teething Toy</h3>
    <span class="spr-review-header-byline"><strong>Jessi</strong> on <strong>Oct 06, 2017</strong></span>
  </div>

  <div class="spr-review-content">
    <p class="spr-review-content-body">Beautifully made item, and the sweetest photo prop. Was a 'must have' piece for my babe. Thanks!</p>
  </div>
  <span class="image_src">https://img0.etsystatic.com/130/0/8943009/iap_300x300.1065344898_2arw8sir.jpg</span>
  <div class="spr-review-footer">
    <a href="#" class="spr-review-reportreview" onclick="SPR.reportReview(49046513);return false" id="report_49046513" data-msg="This review has been reported">Report as Inappropriate</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spr-review" id="spr-review-49046513">
  <div class="spr-review-header">
    <span class="spr-starratings spr-review-header-starratings">
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i><i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
            <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star"></i>
        </span>
    <h3 class="spr-review-header-title">Teething Toy</h3>
    <span class="spr-review-header-byline"><strong>Jessi</strong> on <strong>Oct 06, 2017</strong></span>
  </div>

  <div class="spr-review-content">
    <p class="spr-review-content-body">Beautifully made item, and the sweetest photo prop. Was a 'must have' piece for my babe. Thanks!</p>
  </div>
  <span class="image_src">https://img0.etsystatic.com/130/0/8943009/iap_300x300.1065344898_2arw8sir.jpg</span>
  <div class="spr-review-footer">
    <a href="#" class="spr-review-reportreview" onclick="SPR.reportReview(49046513);return false" id="report_49046513" data-msg="This review has been reported">Report as Inappropriate</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was a trivial mistake.  I tried $(this) in the variable before but forgot the .next. I appreciate your quick response.